# Is this Bug in Spring cloud data flow :tab create 2 additional kafka queues and additional spring boot application for bridge

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

For my used it create additional instance of bridge and two more kafka topic which cause latency issue for data flowing between so -> s

```
So - source
p - processor
s - sink
```

Use-case for creating data flow

1) for new record flow should so => s

2) for update records flow should be so => p => s

```
DSL:
demo1=so|p > :foo
demo2=:demo1.so > :foo
demo3=:foo > s
```

Issues:

1)here data will flow from so -> Input channel/queue ->bridge(internal used demo.so topic) -> foo topic ->output channel/queue ->s

here data is flowing from source to sink using 4 queue which can latency issue compare to data flow like
    source ->kafka ->sink using regular spring boot with kafka consumer/producer using 1 kafka topic**

**This will create so and foo as addition queues  which will consume my resources and hardware.**

2)Also this create additional instance of bridge and in real time i can configure amazon web service to scale my application instances(so,p,s) but who and how scaling processor .bridge is occurred

**This will create additional spring boot application for bridge named as demo2.bridge which will share my resources and hardware**

if I am trying to connect to different stream flows then bridge make sense but with in single and simple stream flow having bridge does not sounds like real time production solution .

**Also if I am developing complex flow which has N fan out then this will create N bridge instance and N+ 2 addition queue/topics consuming additional resources and impacting application performance.**

Can you suggest any better to implement above use case without having additional queues and instance creation

Comment: The way you indented your text made it look like everything is code.  I fixed it for you.

Comment: Well I havent fixed it. But using regular kafka or messaging system I can A->B->C for update and A->C for new records .Which means at max only 3 queues and 3 spring boot application deployment and can use all hardware i provided for it.  But for use case in scdf 4 application (additional one spring binder) and almost 6 kafka queues created due to which over all latency is increased and also resource sharing is increased additional application and queue

Answer (score 0):

Let's replay your example with a concrete use-case since the topology and its description in your post is a bit confusing.

Let's assume you have the following as your primary pipeline.

`stream1 = http --server.port=9001 | filter > :fooTopic`

In this case, `http` and `filter` apps will be connected with a unique topic (i.e., `stream1.http`) and whenever you have a named-channel in the downstream position, SCDF internally uses the bridge-processor to connect the output of `filter` app to a named destination. In total, for the above pipeline, you will have a 2 topics (i.e, `stream1.http` and `fooTopic`).

This is by design.

Now, let's say you'd like to TAP this primary pipeline and dump the "unfiltered" data to the same `fooTopic`.

`stream2 = ":stream1.http > :fooTopic"`

In this case, there will be *no* new topics created. A bridge-processor will be used to connect both the named-destination behind the scenes. This is by design as well.

> if I am trying to connect to different stream flows then bridge make sense but with in single and simple stream flow having bridge does not sounds like real time production solution .

Just to reiterate, a bridge-processor is *only* used when you have a named-destination either at the source or sink position (or both). Please clean-slate your existing setup and retry with a simple example (*also with meaningful apps/names*).